# chef - calling providers from ruby_block

Tags: chef-infra

I know the difference between the compile time and run time behavior in chef, but still could not get around a general problem.
Here  is what I want to do:

- use the git provider to clone something (provide runs at run-time)
- go through some files from the cloned directory and generate some json files (compile time)
- for each json file in the folder: (compile time)

  - run provider x (run-time) with parameters from the json file

Ideally, to fix this, it would be better if I can make it 100% run-time code.
I can put the compile-time code in a **ruby_block** to make it run_time
but then I cannot call any providers from within my ruby block.

How can I deal with this problem?

---

**Updates:**

I've tried a simple code that proves Tensibai's suggestion works:

my recipe:

```
batch 'git_emulation' do
  code "echo hi>C:\\temp\\x.txt"
  action :nothing
end.run_action(:run)

::Dir["C:/temp/*"].each do |path|
  app_go "test" do
    path path
    action :test
  end
end
```

my app_go provider:

```
action :test do
  Chef::Log.info("path = #{@new_resource.path}")
end
```

This prints

> > path = C:\temp\x.txt

meaning that the batch provider ran at compile time.
However, when using git, I get an error:

> STDERR: 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

because the "include_recipe" is not run at run time.
Any ideas?

Comment: I believe if you have one [git resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_git.html) and two [ruby_block](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html) one after the other it should run in that specific order.

Comment: That's right; but what about the loop? As I said, I need to loop through the files and call a provider. Rewriting this provider in a library form will likely solve the problem but that means I have to do a lot of additional work and modify a built-in cookbook.

Comment: I'm unsure to understand what you're doing. Top of my head, set the git clone resource to `action :nothing` and close it with `end.run_action(:sync)` so the git clone happens at compile time. Another option is to do something like [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mostlygeek/1672827)

Comment: This is very interesting. The chef docs only use action=nothing when using notifiers. Why in your code do you have that? Also, is that while loop running at compile time or run time?

Comment: @Tensibai I don't know if you read the post below. I was not able to include the git cookbook at runtime. I'd appreciate if you could comment on that.